# Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. VScode and Android Studio flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

Good day everyone. Please for over 3months now have been having these issues, I have searched online from Google to YouTube and have not gotten an answer to my question or problem. I have installed android studio correctly and flutter doctor is all marked as okay but whenever I want to create a project I will keep seeing Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. The project will finally be created but Flutter will not be found only . Idea folder, modules.xml, and workspace.xml files are the files that will be found inside the .idea folder.  When trying to install through the command line I still found this Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. I have added all path in user and system variable path and yet is not working

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This are the Error: Unable to find git in your PATH shows the same way in Vscode terminal when am trying to install flutter project. Please I will be very happy if this resolved out for me because I need to get back to work. Thank you great developer for your supports and all you do for the community.

flutter install app_test
Returns Error: Unable to find git in your PATH
on the CLI

Comment: I hope you got it fixed... am facing the same issue. mine is worse... when i run git -v from the same terminal i got the error... it returns the git version. also now when i run flutter pub get, the terminal quits

Comment: @BrianNgeywo Are you sure that your environment variables are all set correctly (i.e. you can access those folders)? Also, `git -v` produces what error, or it works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

1. First step Goto this site and download the git setup file
   https://git-scm.com/downloads

2. After downloading, install the Git setup.
3. After installing the set path in an environment variable (if the path is not set)
4. And the last step is to check whether the git is running or not

   (open the command prompt and run the `git` command  and for version checking run `git --version` command.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `C:\Program Files\Git` - without directly targeting any executable.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the executables from your `PATH` variable. There should only be directories in there.

Anyway, the `git` program is probably installed in the `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` directory (what I can see from your screenshots). Let's make sure it can be found globally when you open a cmd-prompt and enter:

```
git -v
```

If it does show you a version number, can you check where it was loaded from?

```
where git
```

Let's make sure if this path is in your global PATH variable.

```
echo %PATH%
```

If this all is correct and you still have the same problem running `C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat` I would open up `flutter.bat` in vscode to see if it re-sets your PATH somewhere or tries to open `git` with an incorrect full-path. Maybe edit it and force it in there by adding somewhere on top:

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%PATH%
```

and make sure it `git` is loaded from this script without a path.

PS. The first line in *flutter.bat* is probably: `@echo off`
You can change this to `@echo on` to have it display each line before executing to make it easier to debug this script.

Answer (score 0):

PATH variable maybe is filled up or has an error, and cannot be interpreted anymore.
Can you do an

`echo %PATH%`

And look, if the bin directory of GIT is there?
What do you get, when you say in that terminal 'git'?
Find a way to execute git, by trial and error, and write down the path.
Copy the flutter.bat to myflutter.bat and add the PATH TO your git bin directory directly, for testing directly in that file.
At the top of (myflutter.cmd) use .cmd instead of .bat for testing.
`PATH=<directory of executable>;%PATH%`
and try again your myflutter.cmd

That could mean, your path is too full, or has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Before configuring the Flutter development environment, I ran the File Explorer as an administrator when using it. So after setting up the development environment, It is normal to launch Flutter using cmd in the File Explorer. But in VScode or IDEA or Android Studio throwing an error：

```
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

1. You can run the command in the command line as administrator:`flutter pub cache clean`.
2. Delete this folder: `C:\flutter\`
3. run `flutter_console.bat` again.

When you run flutter_console.bat cannot use super administrator status.

If you other development environment is right, i think of you will success.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue you are facing is related to Git not being found in your PATH environment variable. Here are some steps you can follow to resolve this problem:

1. Verify Git installation: Ensure that Git is installed on your system and the installation directory is added to the PATH environment variable. You can check if Git is installed by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

   ```
   git --version
   ```

   If Git is installed, you should see the version number. If not, download and install Git from the official website: https://git-scm.com/downloads
2. Verify PATH environment variable: Double-check that you have added the correct path to the Git executable to your PATH environment variable. On Windows, you can edit the PATH variable by following these steps:

   - Open the "Control Panel" and go to "System and Security" > "System" > "Advanced system settings."
   - In the "System Properties" window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
   - In the "Environment Variables" window, locate the "Path" variable under "System variables" or "User variables" (depending on where you added it).
   - Click "Edit" and make sure the path to the Git executable (e.g., "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd") is added. If it's not there, add it and click "OK" to save the changes.
3. Restart your IDE or terminal: After making changes to the PATH environment variable, you may need to restart your IDE or terminal for the changes to take effect.
4. Verify Git in command line: Open a new terminal or command prompt and run the following command to check if Git is recognized:

   ```
   git --version
   ```

   If you see the version number, Git is successfully recognized in your command line.
5. Verify Flutter installation: Double-check that Flutter is installed correctly by running:

   ```
   flutter --version
   ```

   You should see the Flutter version and other related information.
6. Create a new Flutter project: Now, try creating a new Flutter project using the following command:

   ```
   flutter create your_project_name
   ```

   Replace `your_project_name` with the desired name for your project. If everything is set up correctly, the project should be created without any issues.

If you still encounter the "Unable to find git in your PATH" error after following these steps, please ensure that you are using the correct Git executable path and that you have administrative rights to make changes to the system environment variables on your computer.

If the issue persists, consider checking if there are any conflicting PATH variables or third-party tools that might interfere with Git's detection. Additionally, make sure to restart your computer after making changes to environment variables to ensure they take effect.

If you are still having trouble, don't hesitate to reach out to the Flutter or Git communities or forums, where you can find more specific and detailed assistance from experienced developers.